# How to add compression to ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to add a good level of compression to the following ffmpeg command or if it is already good can you help me understand?

I have seen that people might have luck using this command but I dont know how to merge it into mine

```
ffmpeg -i sourceFilePath -vcodec h264 -acodec mp3 newFilePath
```

This is my current command that I am using that I need help understanding why the previous command might be a better solution but how to implement my additional arguments

```
ffmpeg -i sourceFilePath -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3 newFilePath
```

I want to see optimal compression and still have my existing functionality using my additional arguments. I dont know what will produce the best results, this is out of my area of expertise.

Comment: so.... `-vcodec h264` it says that you use `h264` codec while the other uses `libx264`.. they are two separate codec with their own parameter, i guess. have you in random chance tried to throw in that `-acodec mp3` into your current command? or perhaps we should check [the documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html), no?

Comment: `h264`  is a generic id and doesn't represent a specific encoder. It will select the highest priority encoder for that id which may or may not be libx264.